# How to solve $3 \log (x) + \log (2x+3)^3 \le 3 \log (2)$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How can I solve it?

$$3 \log (x) + \log (2x+3)^3 \le 3 \log (2)$$

I have no idea how to solve it.
I didn't find the answer.

Comment: the power in the second summand is inside the $log$ right?

Comment: @thefunkyjunky yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three basic logarithm properties, namely:
$$ \log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab) $$ 
$$ \log(a^k) = k\log(a) $$ and
$$ \log(a) \leq\log(b) \leftrightarrow a \leq b $$ but only iff the logarithm base is $ \gt 1 $. So, with this, you can procede:
$$ 3 \log(x) + \log(2x+3)^3 = 3\log(x) + 3\log(2x + 3) = 3\log(x(2x + 3)) \leq 3\log(2) $$ so
$$ \log(x(2x + 3)) \leq \log(2) \leftrightarrow x(2x + 3) \leq 2$$ assuming logarithm base is greater than 1. Now solve it as a quadratic equation. You get 
$ 2x^2 + 3x - 2 \leq 0 $ which has solutions in the interval $[-2; \frac{1}{2}]$.  Don't forget that logarithm is defined for only positive numbers, so from the statement we have $x\gt 0$ and $2x+3\gt 0 \leftrightarrow x \gt -\frac{3}{2}$. Put all together, solutions are $(0; \frac{1}{2}]$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You inequality can be rewritten as:

$$3 \log (x) + 3\log (2x+3) \le 3 \log (2) $$
Note, that if we had a even power we would need to use the absolute value for the logarithm. Now devide by $3$, which is positive so the inequality does not change.

$$\log (x) + \log (2x+3) \le \log (2)$$
$$ \log \left[x(2x+3)\right] \le \log (2)$$

As the logarithm is a monotonic function you can exponentiate it on both sides to obtain:

$$x\cdot (2x+3) \leq 2 \implies 2x^2+3x-2 \leq 0.$$

Now, find the roots of the quadratic equation. Are you able to complete it from here?

Comment: Thx, very helpful too

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$3\log x(2x+3) \le 3\log 2$$

and then:

$$2x^2+3x \le 2$$

But do not forget about log's defenition area to exclude wrong answers if any